# What are floats? What is a floating decimal point? Are 6. and pi floating numbers?

Tags: types, floating-point

This [site](https://techterms.com/definition/floatingpoint) defines them as "numbers that contain floating decimal points". But what is a "floating decimal"? How is this different from the "normal decimal" used in maths? The site then gives some examples. I wonder if 6. and pi are floating numbers?

The site then writes that "numbers that do not have decimal places are called integers" which is wrong. [Iota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit) is an imaginary number which doesn't contain a "decimal places" and neither is an integer. Is the definition of integer different in programming than maths?

So my questions are: So what are floats? What is a floating decimal point? Are 6. and pi floating numbers?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 are both good / useful references.  note that `float` and `double` in common programming languages often follow the 32 and 64bit IEEE754 binary floating-point standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A floating-point number is ±*significand*•*base*<sup>*exponent*</sup> with a fixed *base* and certain requirements on *significand* and *exponent*. The *exponent* is an integer within a range defined by the format, and the *significand* is a number representable by a numeral using some number of base-*base* digits, where the number of digits is defined by the format.

There may be variations on this basic format. For example, the significand may include a *radix point* (the generalization of a decimal point), so that a format might have significands that are all integers (137., 954., and son ) or that have the radix point at some other fixed location (often just after the first digit, so 1.37, 9.54, and so on). These variations are equivalent, with the exponent range adjusted to compensate.

Thus, +1.23456•10<sup>13</sup> is a decimal floating-point number with six decimal digits. The point “floats” because we multiply by a power of the base that effectively moves the radix point.

At this level of representation, a floating-point format may include some special values, notably +∞, −∞, and NaNs (Not a Number “values” that indicate no number is represented).

The above is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69707681/298225), where there is some additional information.